# Android GridLayout horizontal fill for dynamic fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to layout an Android screen using `GridLayout`, here's a mock layout showing what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Layout Mockup]

I translated that mockup into a layout and here's the result running in the emulator:

[image]

I want the black component in the center to use as much horizontal space as possible, as in the mock layout. But as you can see the white component to the right is using all of the available horizontal space.

I'm getting this error in the log:

```
01-06 08:27:38.045: D/android.widget.GridLayout(7745): horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=71, x1-x0>=64, x2-x1>=128, x3-x2>=1280, x3-x0<=1280 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x3-x0<=1280.
```

I'm using 2 `FrameLayout` components as placeholders for Fragments that are dynamically loaded. So for example depending on which button is clicked in the red panel, a different fragment is loaded into the black panel. Another related problem I'm seeing is that the black panel will change size depending on how many buttons are in the fragment that gets loaded.

I'd prefer to use `GridLayout` if possible, but maybe what I'm trying to do with GridLayout isn't possible? I tried to get this layout working with Linear and Relative layouts but couldn't get it right.

Here's my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/category_placeholder"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:gravity="start"
    />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_placeholder"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:gravity="start"
    />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cart"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        class="com.example.splitscreen.OrderFragment"
        android:background="#4b0082"
        android:gravity="end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:text="xxx"
        android:textColor="#0f0" >
    </TextView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you have `columnCount=3` if you don't need the white content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the "best" approach or not, but I ended up solving this by going back to using nested `LinearLayout`. This seems to give me what I want/need, allowing me to size my components proportionally by providing weights. It took me a little while to get the hang of it, but I finally figured it out. Here's what the result looks like:

[image: Nested LinearLayout]

And here's the layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/category_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="#00f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/cart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            class="com.example.splitscreen.OrderFragment"
            android:background="#4b0082"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" >
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:text="xxx"
        android:textColor="#0f0" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

One minor caveat seems to be that I do get a warning "Nested weights are bad for performance", but at the moment this seems to be the best/only option that I can get to work and layout things the way I want them.